# Jinja can't find template path

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, jinja2

I can't get Jinja2 to read my template file.

`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template.html`

> The simplest way to configure Jinja2 to load templates for your
> application looks roughly like this:
>
> ```
> from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader 
> env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'))
> ```
>
> This will create a template environment with the default settings and
> a loader that looks up the templates in the templates folder inside
> the `yourapplication` python package. Different loaders are available
> and you can also write your own if you want to load templates from a
> database or other resources.   To load a template from this
> environment you just have to call the `get_template()` method which
> then returns the loaded Template:
>
> ```
> template = env.get_template('mytemplate.html')
> ```

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('frontdesk', 'templates'))
template = env.get_template('template.html')
```

My tree ( I have activated the venv @frontdesk )

```
.
├── classes.py
├── labels.txt
├── payments.py
├── templates
├── test.py
└── venv
```

Answer (score 16):

You are using the [`FileSystemLoader` class](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.FileSystemLoader) which has the following init arguments:

```
class FileSystemLoader(BaseLoader):
    def __init__(self, searchpath, encoding='utf-8', followlinks=False):
```

You are initializing it with 2 arguments: `frontdesk` and `templates`, which basically does not make much sense, since the `templates` string would be passed as an `encoding` argument value. If you want to continue using `FileSystemLoader` as a template loader, use it this way:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('frontdesk/templates'))
template = env.get_template('index.html')
```

---

Or, if you meant to use the [`PackageLoader` class](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.PackageLoader):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('frontdesk', 'templates'))
template = env.get_template('index.html')
```

In this case you need to make sure `frontdesk` is a [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) - in other words, make sure you have `__init__.py` file inside the `frontdesk` directory.

Comment: Also, in the PackageLoader class example, `'templates'` is the relative path of the directory which holds the templates (relative to the package `frontdesk`).